# PHP Website Sessions for Multiple Users are not Disjoint

Tags: php, html

I am new to PHP, but I created a website with a login, register, and personalized homepage for different users. 
I have three users and three tabs in my web browser with the sessions open. Sometimes, if I click on go back to home in say user1, the button would return me to user2's home page.

What do you think it is wrong?
Thank you.

Comment: If you want to add a different question, then please add a new question; don't edit your existing one

Comment: Admins don't allow me to post questions, because of rep. They themselves told me to edit my questions. Oh, Is that why you upvoted this one? So, that I can ask it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to simulate all three users yourself, just using tabs in your browser. Then you are going to have collisions -- whatever tab was loaded last will set a session cookie, overwriting the other tabs' cookies. All tabs will then be effectively using that last tab's session.

Try testing it with two different browsers -- you'll see they don't conflict, because the browsers don't share their cookies.

Comment: There are lots of ways to handle that scenario (using on-page JavaScript variables, for example) -- there's still only one true session going across all of the tabs.

Comment: That could be (1) a cookie problem, (2) a problem with data in `$_SESSION`, or (3) a more serious problem with your login/authentication logic. Without more information and sample code, it's impossible to say.

Comment: It depends on your logic; if you are using $_SESSION to store user ids or something and have gotten them messed up somehow, you could be retrieving the wrong user's info. You should consider starting a new question with more details (verifying the session ids for different users are different, comparing the data in $_SESSION, etc.).

Comment: I am barely using $_SESSIONS I mostly pass values around through forms. How do I verify the session ids? And, how do I correct this once I find an inconsistency? I have user_id variables passed around through forms. if I find that somehow somewhere $user_id conflicts with $_SESSION['id'] are different what's the command to retrieve my session?

Comment: You can simply do a `var_dump()` of `$_SESSION` and `$_COOKIE`. If the values for 2 or more users are the same when you don't expect them to be, you have a problem.